# How I can Call a method that there is in server layer from client layer in BLAZOR

Tags: blazor

I have a Date converter method that wrote in server layer and I need to use that method in client layer.
How I can Call a method that there is in server layer from client layer in BLAZOR. Thanks for your Attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the client side to the server side there has to be a connection. Its easy to get drawn into thinking all the code is available because it often shows in the same solution, whereas its really running on a different machine.

You'll need to create a service and make the function you need to call in that, then inject the service from the clientside, to be able to call the method.

Look at the Blazor sample app, if you havent already. The weather option is doing exactly this.